# OrdinalEncoder' object has no attribute '_missing_indices'

Tags: python, azure, scikit-learn, ordinal

I was able to train the model and deployed the endpoint successfully in Azure.
However, when I was testing the endpoint: it gives me the error below:

```
Failed to test real-time endpoint
{"status_code":400,"message":"'OrdinalEncoder' object has no attribute '_missing_indices'"}
```

In my model, I was using sklearn pipeline with ordinalEncoder, running on sklearn version 0.24.1. A portion of the code is as below:

```
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'))         
])

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('ordinal', OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
])

features_preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('numeric',     numeric_transformer,     cols_tofill.values),
        ('categorical', categorical_transformer, ['Country','Status'])
    ], remainder='passthrough')
```

Been trying to debug but it is difficult if I do not know what does the error mean. Can someone please advise? Thank you so much for your help.

Here is the test data which I passed into the 'Test' tab of the Azure endpoint:

```
{  "data": [{"Country": "Japan",
             "Year": 2021,
             "Status": "Developed",
             "Adult_Mortality": 52,
             "Infant_Deaths": 1,
             "Alcohol": 1.9,
             "Percentage_Expenditure": 8000,
             "Hepatitis_B": 98,
             "Measles": 0,
             "BMI": 33,
             "Under-five_Deaths": 0,
             "Polio": 90,
             "Total_Expenditure": 5,
             "Diphtheria": 99,
             "HIV/AIDS": 0.1,
             "GDP": 57000,
             "Population": 6000000,
             "thinness_1-19_years": 2,
             "thinness_5-9_years": 2,
             "Income_composition_of_resources": 0.9,
             "Schooling": 15}],
   "method": "predict"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This `Failed to test real-time endpoint {"status_code":400,"message":"'OrdinalEncoder' object has no attribute '_missing_indices'"}` error means you have one or more missing indices, you can try following ways to handle it:

```
 # stores the missing indices per category
        self._missing_indices = {}
        for cat_idx, categories_for_idx in enumerate(self.categories_):
            for i, cat in enumerate(categories_for_idx):
                if is_scalar_nan(cat):
                    self._missing_indices[cat_idx] = i
                    continue

         if np.dtype(self.dtype).kind != "f" and self._missing_indices:
            raise ValueError(
                "There are missing values in features "
                f"{list(self._missing_indices)}. For OrdinalEncoder to "
                "passthrough missing values, the dtype parameter must be a "
                "float"
            )

        return self
```

You can refer to [scikit-learn_encoders.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/5f0a69585bf0d8e010419fec113f36405fab1397/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py#:%7E:text=%23%20stores%20the%20missing%20indices%20per%20category) and [sklearn.impute.MissingIndicator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.MissingIndicator.html)

Comment: Hi @DeepDave-MT, thank you so much for the quick reply. I am using the simpleimputer to ensure that all blank/nan values are filled. I am not so sure why this error occur in the first place where there should be no missing. Is my understanding incorrect? It was trained successfully on the train data but when I pass in the test data (all non blanks), it failed with the error. So I am kinda confused. Will be great if you can help with more detail explanations?

Comment: You are already using simpleimputer so it's strange why this error occurred. Do share the specific code with the line number where this error occurred

Comment: I have edited the post above to include the test data which I passed in that resulted in the error. To be honest, the portion of the code is the only place where I call the ordinalEncoder. If you can point me the location to get the necessary logs inside Azure, I can pass them to you. Here in Azure, everything is a black box, it is so hard to debug around. :)

Comment: I just changed the ordinal to use OneHotEncoder and it works with the same set of data. But I am still curious on why it just doesn't work for ordinalEncoder.

Comment: Suggest you ask the same on [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com)

Comment: OK, thanks for taking the time to look at this. Appreciated!

Comment: I've gotten this error as a result of version discrepancy. If you have any model pre-trained on scikit-learn==0.24.X and try to load and run on 1.X.X you'll get this error.